# MariaDB stored functions

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, mariadb, stored-functions

I currently have all of my sql queries written in my PHP files, within each class method.  Is it possible to move all of these queries into stored procedures or stored functions in the database & simply pass the corresponding values / arguments into them from PHP?

I have read some of the documentation & it still appears unclear.

Thank you.  :)

Comment: Of course. You may create stored procedure and call it instead of executing the query placed into SP's body. You may create user-defined function and use it instead of an expression placed into UDF's body.

Answer (score 0):

Most queries can be moved into stored procedures, but probably not all of them. See mariadb's documentation on [which SQL statements cannot be used in stored procedures](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/stored-routine-limitations/):

> - ALTER VIEW; you can use CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW instead. LOAD DATA and
> - LOAD TABLE. INSERT DELAYED is permitted, but the statement is handled
> - as a regular INSERT.
> - LOCK TABLES and UNLOCK TABLES.
> - References to local variables within prepared statements inside a stored routine (use user-defined variables instead).
> - BEGIN (WORK) is treated as the beginning of a BEGIN END block, not a transaction, so START TRANSACTION needs to be used instead.
> - The number of permitted
>   recursive calls is limited to max_sp_recursion_depth. If this variable
>   is 0 (default), recursivity is disabled. The limit does not apply to
>   stored functions.
> - Most statements that are not permitted in prepared
>   statements are not permitted in stored programs. See Prepare
>   Statement:Permitted statements for a list of statements that can be
>   used.
> - SIGNAL, RESIGNAL and GET DIAGNOSTICS are exceptions, and may be
>   used in stored routines

Having said this, even though a SQL statement can be moved into a stored procedure, you may not necessarily want to do that due to code complexity or performance reasons.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Nothing that complex.  I am doing the simple CRUD operations on the data.  More complex tasks are done directly with sql queries manually or in PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: what level of complexity would negate its use?  If the query runs quickly when passed into the db from PHP, would that suffice as a bench test?  Or do stored procedures / functions run at different speeds?  And thus require their own testing?

Comment: I'm sorry, but there is no generic answer to your question. You need to evaluate / test each individual case you want to move into a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELIMITER $$
create procedure `accounting`.`delete_invoice_line` (invoice_line_id INT)
BEGIN
delete from invoice_line where id = invoice_line_id;
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I had to figure the format for creating the procedure.  I am following this pattern & it appears to be working properly.  Then granting execute privileges for the user name.

Thank you all for your input.  :)